# Keep the order after formatting date to character vector

Tags: ggplot2, radix

I want to make a frequency plot of dates in a dataframe. The plot should be faceted for year and the dates should be displayed in the format "Apr 01".

Here is may data

```
x = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-01", "2018-04-15", "2018-05-01", "2018-05-15",
      "2019-04-01", "2019-04-15", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-15"))

df = data.frame(date = sample(x,30, replace = TRUE))
df$year <-  format(df$date, "%Y")
```

If i create a faceted plot with the original date variable, both plots does not match, because the whole date range is displayed on the x axis. However, I want to match the day and month information.

library(ggplot2)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.Date(date), y = ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(year ~ ., scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "weeks" , date_labels = "%b-%d") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Now I create a character vector, keeping the day and month information. This is fine, but the format of the date is not pretty.

```
df$date_working <- format(df$date, "%m-%d")

ggplot(df, aes(x=date_working, y = ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(year ~ ., scales = "free_x") +
  labs(title="right order")
```

[image]

Therefore, I create another date variable. However, the problem is, that this variable does not keep the right order.

```
df$date_appreciated <- format(df$date, "%d %b")

ggplot(df, aes(x=date_appreciated, y = ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(year ~ ., scales = "free_x") +
  labs(title="wrong order")
```

[image]

Does anybody have a solution. I need to create the "date_appreciated" variable while keeping the order of the "date_working" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get there by formatting your `date_working` column as a factor variable using the `{forcats}` package (this package is included as part of the `{tidyverse}`.

By contrast to `base::as.factor()` which automatically creates factor levels based on the alphabetical sorting of the underlying variable, `forcats::as_factor()` by default creates levels based on the current sort order of the data.  This allows you to generate "nicely formatted" date labels while keeping the correct sort order:

```
# load required libraries
library(tidyverse)

# your original code
x = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-01", "2018-04-15", "2018-05-01", "2018-05-15",
                 "2019-04-01", "2019-04-15", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-15"))

df = data.frame(date = sample(x,30, replace = TRUE))
df$year <-  format(df$date, "%Y")

# sort df by date using dplyr::arrange %>% create a new column called
# date_working which is equal to the date column, but with"nicer" formatting and
# then convert the column  to factor using forcats::as_factor date factor
# version of date variable that is sorted appropriately using forcats
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(date_working = format(date, "%d %b") %>% forcats::as_factor())

# generate the plot output as before, except now it should be ordered correctly
ggplot(df, aes(x=date_working, y = ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(year ~ ., scales = "free_x") +
  labs(title="right order")
```

[image]

In fact, if you wanted, you could have created this formatting "on the fly" during your ggplot call. The following code chunk should yield the same plot as the one shown above:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = format(date, "%d %b") %>% forcats::as_factor(), y = ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(year ~ ., scales = "free_x") +
  labs(title="right order")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is weird and I really can't explain it to me. But it is not working, i get the following warning: 50: In mutate_impl(.data, dots, caller_env()) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate the error you are getting. I have updated my answer to include the loading of the `{tidyverse}` library and the generation of the data frame itself.  The code runs without error for me.  Do you have the most recent version of the `{tidyverse}` package installed and loaded?

Comment: I am sorry, it is also difficult for me to replicate the error. With the test data it ran after the 4th trial. But with my original data theres sth. wrong. maybe, because of the attributes. I don't know why, but in my original data set, (almost) all dates from 2019 came in the order behind the dates of 2018 once I created the variable outside the pipe. Creating the variable df$date_working <- format(df$date, "%m-%d") and use that variable for arrange() did the job.